# Conditional CTE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to write a dynamic query. I've tried to simplify this as best as I can. `@Condition` and `@Filter` are the dynamic inputs of the query.

There are two cases:

- If `@Condition` is `TRUE`, then do not filter the `data` on the presence of any `metadata`
- Otherwise, find the rows of `metadata` that match a certain filer, and filter the `data` on those.

Pseudo code a little bit like this:

```
WITH selected_metadata AS (
    IF (@Condition = TRUE) {
        -- Do not filter on metadata
        SELECT NULL;
    }
    ELSE {
        -- Find the matching metadata rows
        SELECT id FROM metadata WHERE field = @Filter
    }
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM data
WHERE
    (
        -- Ignore the metadata filter
        selected_metadata IS NULL 
        OR
        -- Filter on metadata
        data.metadataid IN (selected_metadata)
    )
    ...more filters
```

I think there might be easier ways to do this without a CTE, but because of how the query looks in real life, I think I need to split it up to minimize complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to set those condition in where instead of CTE directly.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM data
WHERE
    (
        -- Ignore the metadata filter
        @Condition = TRUE
        OR
        -- Filter on metadata
        @Condition = FALSE AND data.metadataid IN (SELECT ID FROM selected_metadata AND field = @Filter)
    )
    ...more filters
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I want to do, but would it be possible to do via a CTE instead? I think the execution planner can make more consistent desisions if I don't do it as a sub select (not sure though)

Comment: @joel . . . I don't think a subquery versus CTE is going to affect how Postgres optimizes the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok. I'm doing some tests right now with a sub query instead, hoping it'll work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
WITH selected_metadata AS (
  -- Find the matching metadata rows
  SELECT id FROM metadata WHERE field = @Filter OR @Condition <> TRUE
)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: In this case there is no way for me to know if `selected_metadata` is empty because `@Condition` was `FALSE` or because there were no matching rows. If `@Condition` is `FALSE`, I want all the rows from `data`